# How YouTube recognize copyrighted music tracks?

Tags: flash, adobe, youtube

What tecnology **Youtube** use to recognize the copyrighted music tracks ?

Comment: I don' really know f this question belongs here ... But this may be a starting point: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/09/youtube-vs-fair-use.html

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acoustic_fingerprint

Comment: Shazam http://laplacian.wordpress.com/2009/01/10/how-shazam-works/
http://www.redcode.nl/blog/2010/06/creating-shazam-in-java/